# How to get all array elements value in multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get all array elements value in each div? I try with my code but it seem value output is duplicate..

Here is my html code.
https://jsfiddle.net/xvrp98wz/1/#&togetherjs=HzjPB5VztO

```
<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="3">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="6">
</div>

 <div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="9">
</div>
```

and javascript

```
var Items_parent = [];
var Items_sub = [];

  $(".parent").each(function(e){

              $("input[name^='sub']").each(function () {
                   var val = $(this).val();
                   var date = $(this).attr('data-date');
                   
                   var item = {date : val};
                   Items_sub.push($(this).val());
              });
              
              Items_parent.push(Items_sub);

  });
  
  console.log(Items_parent);
```

Comment: What format of output are you attempting to build? Also what type of inputs are those? I assume checkboxes or radios from the context...?

Comment: Input is just a text and I want output like an array  console.log(Items_parent);

Comment: _“but it seem value output is duplicate”_ - of course it is, because you are looping over all `.parent` elements, and inside that loop, you are looping over _all_ `input[name^='sub']` elements, _each time_. You need to either limit this selection to those inputs under the current parent - or loop over _just_ the inputs in the first place (depending on what exactly you actually want to achieve.)

Comment: @banku Have you seen my answer below ? I have provided three solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use one `$.each` to get `data-date`. Instead of `.attr` you can also use `.data` to get the dates of each input which are in the parent class.

> Since its a bit unclear what you trying to store. I have added a scenarios which considering your question.

You can choose what suits you *best* from the below three working `demos`.

**Demo:** Showing input value and relevant datadate of that input

```js
var Items_parent = [];

$(".parent input").each(function(index, data) {
  //get date
  var date = $(this).data('date');
  //name
  var value = $(this).val()
  //Push date
  var obj = {};
  //Obj
  obj[value] = date
  //Push
  Items_parent.push(obj);
});

console.log(Items_parent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="3">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="6">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="9">
</div>
```

**Demo:** Showing each input date as {date: XXXX-XX-XX}

```js
var Items_parent = [];

$(".parent input").each(function(index, data) {
  //get date
  var date = $(this).data('date');
  //Push date
  Items_parent.push({
    date: date
  });
});

//All item
console.log(Items_parent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="3">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="6">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="9">
</div>
```

**Demo:** Showing each input as {sub[X]: XXXX-XX-XX}

If you want to get the name of the each input with its date then you do something like this.

```js
var Items_parent = [];

$(".parent input").each(function(index, data) {
  //get date
  var date = $(this).data('date');
  //name
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  //Push date
  var obj = {};
  //Obj
  obj[name] = date
  //Push
  Items_parent.push(obj);
});

console.log(Items_parent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="3">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="6">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="9">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the context of the question and the comment under it, it appears you're attempting to create a nested array of objects. To do that you can use `map()`, like this:

```js
let output = $('.parent').map((i, parent) => 
  [$(parent).find('input').map((i, input) => ({ date: input.dataset.date })).get()]
).get();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="3">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="6">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
  <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06" value="9">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Items_parent = [];
var Items_sub = [];

$(".parent input[name^='sub']").each(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var date = $(this).attr('data-date');

  var item = {date : val};
  Items_sub.push($(this).val());
});
              
Items_parent.push(Items_sub);
document.write(Items_parent);
console.log(Items_parent);
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="1">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="2">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="3">
    </div>
    
    <div class="parent">
      <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="4">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="5">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="6">
    </div>
    
     <div class="parent">
      <input name="sub[0]" data-date="2020-08-04" value="7">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-05" value="8">
      <input name="sub[1]" data-date="2020-08-06"value="9">
    </div>
    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```